# Getting input on number of rows then drawing a star in the console

Tags: c++

I am currently in week 3 of a c++ college course. We are working on for loops. I am having an issue with the homework.

We are using nested for loops to draw a diamond out to the console made of `*`s. The homework part of this was to get the user input for the number of rows in the diamond, then print that diamond. I can get user input but I can not get the diamond shape I am left with a triangle.

Any help is appriciated.

This is my current code:

C++

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int x;
int y;
int rowNum;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    cout << " Enter the Numbers of rows you would like between 3 and 15: " << endl;
    cin >> rowNum;

        for(x = 1; x <= 10; x++) //outer loop
        {
            for(y = 1; y <= rowNum; y++){
                if (y <= (10 - x))
                cout << " ";
                else
                cout << "*";
            }
        cout << endl;
        }


    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: Why do you have two for loops and this magic number 10? I think it is a good idea to implement this without input. Let us say you define a variable rowNum = 5 and then try to get the for loop working. This does not work at this point

Comment: `I can't figure out where to put my user input variable to make it define the number of rows.` It's not clear. What do you mean by that? U already have the row numbers as input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to do 2 changes in your code to make it work:

1. Replace all **10** with **rowNum**
2. Second outer loop should be

   **for (x = rowNum; x >= 1; x--)** //outer loop

Note: It works fine only for an even number of rows. You will need to handle the case of an odd number of rows.

Updated code:

```
std::cout << " Enter the Numbers of rows you would like between 3 and 15: " << std::endl;
std::cin >> rowNum;

for (x = 1; x <= rowNum; x++) //outer loop
{
    for (y = 1; y < x; y++) {
        if (y <= (rowNum - x))
            std::cout << " ";
        else
            std::cout << "*";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
for (x = rowNum; x >= 1; x--) //outer loop
{
    for (y = 1; y < x; y++) {
        if (y <= (rowNum - x))
            std::cout << " ";
        else
            std::cout << "*";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks that's exactly what I was looking for now time to work through figuring out odd numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Think about this expression in your if statement

```
y <= (10 - x)
```

Do you think that expression is correct if the number of rows is 10? I guess it is.

Now would that expression be correct if the number of rows was different, say 20 rows? Obviously not, the correct expression in that case would be

```
y <= (20 - x)
```

So we want to use different values in the formula depending on the number of rows. How to do that? Well that's what variables are for. You have a variable `rowNum` whose value is the number of rows. So the correct formula that will work for any number of rows is

```
y <= (rowNum - x)
```

BTW it does help when you are thinking about these things to pick good variable names. `rowNum` sounds more like the number of the row, not the number of rows. So pick a better variable name, e.g. `numberOfRows`.