# C++ School project drawing a diamond to console made of * characters

Tags: c++

I previously asked for help with a school assignment after getting help from several of the good people of stack overflow I've hit another snag. For some reason my program wont print an odd number of * to the console so I get a miss shaped diamond. Would anyone have any ideas on how I can fix that issue?

Here is my code:

```
   using namespace std;

   int x;
   int y;
   int rowNum;


   int main (int argc, char *argv[]){

       cout << " Enter the Numbers of rows you would like between 3 and 15: " << endl;
       cin >> rowNum;
    
       if((3 <= rowNum)&&( rowNum<= 15))
       {    
           for (x = 1; x <= rowNum; x++) //outer loop
           {
              for (y = 1; y <= x; y++) {
                  if (y <= (rowNum - x))
                     cout << " ";
                  else
                      cout << "*";
            }
             cout << endl;
         }
        for (x = rowNum; x >= 1; x--) //outer loop
        {
              for (y = 1; y <= x; y++) 
              {
                  if (y <= (rowNum - x))
                       cout << " ";
                  else
                       cout << "*";
               }
               cout << endl;
           }
       }
       else{
           cout << "invalid number try again";
       }
       return 0;
   }
```

Comment: Try making a more focused [mre]. Don't ask me to enter a number of rows; just set `rowNum` to the smallest number that demonstrates the problem (and eliminate any code that is no longer needed after this change). Eliminate your second loop over `x` unless your first loop over `x` is working perfectly (in which case, eliminate your first loop and keep the second). This should produce a triangle instead of a diamond, but that's fine as we are not grading your homework. Figure out what the triangle should look like, then add your expected and actual output to your question.

Comment: This looks pretty similar to the code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65937431/11748454) :-). Start by understanding the code, e.g. add a `$` character at the end of each row so you can see the white characters and why you have so many blank rows. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65974877/edit) your question and provide an example of the expected output in the case of an odd and even number of rows.